# Solr, clustering (carrot) and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis, noclassdeffounderror

i'm running Solr 3.4 and would like to use the clusteringComponent.
Following this tutorial: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent in combination with default entries at the solrconfig.xml i have the following configuration @solrconfig.xml

```
  <searchComponent name="clustering" 
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:true}"
                   class="org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >

    <!-- Declare an engine -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>
      <str name="LingoClusteringAlgorithm.desiredClusterCountBase">20</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>


<requestHandler name="/cl" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

    <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
    <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
    <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>

    <!-- Fields to cluster on -->
    <str name="carrot.title">UEBSCHRIFT</str>
    <str name="carrot.snippet">TEXT</str>
  </lst>
```

So if i try to use the requestHandler `http://server:8080/solr/mycore/cl?q=*:*` i get the following Java exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.carrotsearch.hppc.ObjectContainer
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.carrot2.text.preprocessing.pipeline.BasicPreprocessingPipeline.&lt;init&gt;(BasicPreprocessingPipeline.java:106)
    at org.carrot2.text.preprocessing.pipeline.CompletePreprocessingPipeline.&lt;init&gt;(CompletePreprocessingPipeline.java:32)
    at org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm.&lt;init&gt;(LingoClusteringAlgorithm.java:129)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1325)
    at org.carrot2.util.pool.SoftUnboundedPool.borrowObject(SoftUnboundedPool.java:80)
    at org.carrot2.core.PoolingProcessingComponentManager.prepare(PoolingProcessingComponentManager.java:128)
    at org.carrot2.core.Controller.process(Controller.java:333)
    at org.carrot2.core.Controller.process(Controller.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.carrot2.CarrotClusteringEngine.cluster(CarrotClusteringEngine.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.ClusteringComponent.process(ClusteringComponent.java:91)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.carrotsearch.hppc.ObjectContainer
    at java.lang.Throwable.&lt;init&gt;(Throwable.java:80)
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.&lt;init&gt;(ClassNotFoundException.java:76)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:923)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
    ... 31 more
```

The point is, that I have no idea what this mean. I'm searching for hours without finding an solution.

By the way: I'm running on tomcat with the following options:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true"
```

(is this still required in Solr 3.4?)

The catalina option is part of the java command, as you can see with `ps -efa`

> /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1_6_0-ibm-1.6.0/jre//bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat6
>   -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat6/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Does anyone has an idea what i could do to solve this problem?

//Update:
if i add hppc-0.3.4-jdk15.jar, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.mahout.math.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm.&lt;init&gt;(LingoClusteringAlgorithm.java:134)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D
    at java.lang.Throwable.&lt;init&gt;(Throwable.java:80)
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.&lt;init&gt;(ClassNotFoundException.java:76)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:923)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
    ... 29 more
```

it looks like, i have to install an mahout archive, but i think, all packages for clustering are included in Solr 3.4?! It looks like, i'm on the wrong way?!

Comment: Please reformat the stack trace error into a readable shape (with proper indentations)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse i hope, it's better to read now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Solr's default packaging (this is officially supported)? It ships with Jetty and will save you the headaches connected with classpath because things are already configured.

Answering your question, you'll need all the JARs from Solr's default clustering extension folders; for 4.0 alpha this would be: contrib/clustering/lib/*.jar

carrot2-core-3.5.0.jar
hppc-0.3.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar
mahout-collections-0.3.jar
mahout-math-0.3.jar
simple-xml-2.4.1.jar

Comment: Hey, thank you. That's it. It works. Why you know, which java archive is required?  ---- ">Why not use Solr's default packaging (this is officially supported)? " <- We will discuss that internal. Right now Solr is running @ tomcat with only the needed Java archives. The All-inclusive-default Solr package comes with all those different thinks, we don't use (right now).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Solr with tomcat as a seperate instance, you would need to copy the jars so that they are available for Solr.

Quote from [README.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_4/solr/example/README.txt)

> NOTE: This Solr example server references certain Solr jars outside of
>   this server directory for non-core modules with  statements in
>   solrconfig.xml.  If you make a copy of this example server and wish to
>   use the ExtractingRequestHandler (SolrCell), DataImportHandler (DIH),
>   UIMA, the clustering component, or other modules in "contrib", you
>   will need to copy the required jars into solr/lib or update the paths
>   to the jars in your solrconfig.xml.

Check for the clustering and carrot jars in solrconfig.xml.
Probably you are missing `hppc-0.3.4-jdk15.jar`

Comment: libdir is  `<lib dir="/opt/solr/lib" />` and insight the libdir is `apache-solr-clustering-3.4.0.jar`. I tried also to copy `hppc-0.3.4-jdk15.jar` and `carrot2-core-3.4.0.jar` to libdir. But the problem still exists. If i take a look to the solr wiki I can read: `>3.1 Carrot2 is fully integrated into Solr and does not require special downloads.` shouldn't it work out of the box??

Comment: please take a look at my update. it looks like i need some mahout package. I thought everything i need is insight the `apache-solr-clustering-3.4.0.jar` file - is'n it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Mahout Math package?

It seems to be a separate package.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.mahout.math.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

With solR 4 copy this file in folder conf

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/labs/alike/trunk/demo/solrhome/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml